# Identifying military uniform which is probably French or Italian

Tags: military-records, photo-identification, italy, france, military-practices

I'm trying to ID someone's military uniform in an old family photo. Not a lot of clues to go on, except that the man was probably French or Italian, maybe in a colonial setting.

Can you recognize the insignia on the cap?

[image: Black & white photo of a man in military uniform]

Tried to look it up myself but didn't have any luck.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://history.stackexchange.com/